# How to get a Date of a certificate revocation and compare it to signingTime in Java

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle, certificate-revocation

I have a X509Certificate. And I need to verify that Date of signing time is less than revocation time. Here's what I mean. Imagine that someone stole a private key of a signer and signed some fake document, but CA was on time and revocated it. So, the certificate and all the documents, signed after revocation time are not valid anymore. Here's what I need to do in order to follow the algorithm:

1. Get singing time from pkcs7 file (I've already got the certificate from this file)
2. Find CRL URL in the certificate, download it
3. Check whether id of certificate is present if this CRL
4. If so, get the revocation time
5. Check that signing time is less than revocation

Is there "ready-baked" code for it? Cause getting CRL from certificate is quite a nightmare. The library I use is Bouncy Castle.

Comment: In this project you can find all you need, but your question is to broad to be answered here.   https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/collection/digital-signature-service

Comment: By "signing time," you mean when the PKCS 7 signed-data was signed, not when the signer's certificate was issued. Right?

Answer (score 0):

> Check that signing time is less than revocation

The signing time of an X.509 certificate is not present in the certificate. Nor is it relevant. The only times that are relevant are the not-before and not-after times. It is possible to sign a certificate in advance of its not-before date. It is also possible, although pointless, to sign it after its not-after date.

What you need is the relevant Certificate Revocation List, not the signing time. If the certificate has been revoked it can only be because it was *never* valid.